# c# How to detect a destroyed clone

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a cooking simulator game on Unity, where when you click on the raw food plate, after x seconds it will generate a clone of the cooked food on the grill. If I don't click (destroy) this cooked food after x seconds, then this cooked food will become a burned food.

```
void OnMouseDown()
{
    // food item 1
    if (gameObject.name == "blobraw1") {
        StartCoroutine(cookandburn("blobraw1"));
    }
    else if (gameObject.name.Contains("blobcooked1")) {
        if(corder.SearchandRemove(gameObject)) {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        };
    }
}

public IEnumerator cookandburn(string rawFoodName) {
    float x = Random.Range(MinX, MaxX);
    float y = Random.Range(MinY, MaxY);

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(cooktime);
    if (rawFoodName == "blobraw1")
    {
        // generate raw food
        Instantiate(cooked1, new Vector3(x, y, 10), Quaternion.identity);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(burntime);
        // generate burned food if condition doesn't satisfy
        Instantiate(burned1, new Vector3(x, y, 10), Quaternion.identity);
    }
```

Currently, I am able to destroy the cooked food item, but after x seconds the burned script will be run and initiate the burned version of the food at the exact location. I can't think of a way to detect when the cooked version is destroyed and tell the program not to create an instance of the burned one.

Comment: Why not create `enum FoodState { cooked, raw, burnt ...}` and then assign this enum to object `food` and before actions check if your `fState == FoodState.cooked` do something etc...

Comment: In addition to what AleksaRistic already said: I would not instantiate a complete "clone" but rather enable/disable or Instantiate/destroy a certain child mesh for the current state instead but always keep the same parent object with the controller script on it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `isDestroyed = false` flag. After the food is destroyed, make it true. Check the condition before instantiating the burned food. Once the coroutine finished, make the flag false again. If you want to use in other scripts, it might come handy to set flag is a `PlayerPrefs.SetInt("isDestroyed", 0)`

```
bool is Destroyed = false; //Define this on top of the script
public IEnumerator cookandburn(string rawFoodName) {
float x = Random.Range(MinX, MaxX);
float y = Random.Range(MinY, MaxY);

yield return new WaitForSeconds(cooktime);
if (rawFoodName == "blobraw1")
{
    // generate raw food
    Instantiate(cooked1, new Vector3(x, y, 10), Quaternion.identity);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(burntime);
    // generate burned food if condition doesn't satisfy
    // Check that if the object was destroyed
    if(!isDestroyed){
        Instantiate(burned1, new Vector3(x, y, 10), Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
isDestroyed = false;
}
```

Comment: After doing what you said, the problem still persists. The burned version is still showing after checking isDestroyed equals true. I think it's because after the clone has been destroyed, the instance disappears as well. But somehow the original script is still running, and it gets to the burned destroy statements???? I am super confused on why it's still happening -.-

Comment: Add some `debug.log` statements to check the code and execution order. In addition to that, if you want to hold the instance and manipulate it, define an empty GameObject globally and every time you instantiate an object assign it to the game object that you defined. Like, `GameObject obj;                        obj = Instantiate(...)`